# Leaflet equivalent to google toSpan() function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, gis, leaflet

I'm moving my web app from Google maps JS api to leaflet.

Everything is going well so far until I tried to calculate the "span" value.

In Google maps api I just wrote

```
map.getBounds().toSpan().lng();
```

But I cant find this function in leaflet api documentation.

If there isn't an equivalent to this function Is there anybody who know how am I suppose to implement this function in leaflet by myself?

Thanks a lot.

Idan.

Comment: According to the Google documentation `toSpan` converts the given map bounds to a lat/lng span. What is a lat/lng span? Perhaps you can edit your question and explain what the function actually does.

Comment: You'd either have to do the math on the `LatLngBounds` object returned by `getBounds()` in your code, or extend `LatLngBounds` with an appropriate `toSpan()` method ... see also http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds

Comment: iH8 I can't explain what this function does, if I knew I would not ask.
@HartmutHolzgraefe: if you can give an exemple to how am I suppose to do it - it will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic calculation is:

**Latitude:**`bounds.getNorth()-bounds.getSouth()`
**Longitude:**`bounds.getEast()-bounds.getWest()`

additionally must catch the case where Longitude is <=0

**Longitude:**`(bounds.getEast()-bounds.getWest()+360)%360||360`

Comment: this is very old but, you help me a lot! with this same issue! thanks